# Retain cycle created - need confirmation

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have been going questions about retain cycle but most of them talk about defining a block explictly and holding a strong reference to it. None of them talks about just passing an inline block.
My understanding is that just passing block in a function as an argument, does not create a strong reference. But i just want to make sure I havent misunderstood.

So the question is:
Does passing a block in a member function create a strong reference?

```
    [self someFunctionWithCompletionCallback:^{
        [self completionFunctionality];
    }];
```

In this case is self holding a strong reference on the block being passed?

That would decide if I need to pass in weakSelf or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what that `someFunctionWithCompletionCallback:` does. If the method stores that block in a strong member variable, for example, it would cause a retain cycle. If the method just calls the block during its execution and does not store it, no permanent retain cycle is created.

Note that something like this:

```
- (void)someFunctionWithCompletionCallback:(void (^)())completionBlock {
    dispatch_async(^{ completionBlock() }); 
}
```

Will retain `self` temporarily (until the async dispatch is completed), since dispatch_async will retain its block, which will retain the completion block, which will retain self.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responses.. very helpful.. i am marking this as an answer because it points out an interesting point. I am not retaining any of my blocks .. just execute it from the called function. Just out of curiosity in what cases should i retain a block. Saw an answer here which also left me thinking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915250/retain-cycle-in-completion-block/12916493#12916493

Answer (score 3):

When you call `[self completionFunctionality];` in block body it (block) retains `self` so it creates `strong` reference. When execution of block is finished, it becomes out of scope, as result it would be removed from stack and block breaks strong reference to `self`. It means that `self` couldn't be dealloced until block execution is finished. So it isn't `retain cycle` in common understanding.

Comment: Are you sure about this? What if the block is called again? Are you sure it breaks a reference after the block runs once?

Comment: @JesseRusak I've updated my answer a little. Block breaks a reference when it's removed from stack. Block is removing from stack when it becomes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the definition of a cycle is A->B->A (where '->' means 'retains').  In your question, B is a block and A is an object defining the block literal.  B->A is certainly true, because blocks retain objects referred to within them and B refers to A.

But does A->B?  That's up to A.  Just passing an object doesn't retain it (imagine if that were the case, infinite retains everywhere!).  So how does A handle B?  If A copies or retains B, then A->B, and you have a cycle.  If it doesn't, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't create retain cycle. It would be retain cycle if the block was for example  a strong or copy property